# react-dropdown-tree-select ,After the child nodes are selected one by one, the parent node is not automatically selected. Is there a solution?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropdown-tree-select

I'm using react-dropdown-tree-select , After the child nodes are selected one by one, the parent node is not automatically selected. Is there a solution?

```
import React from 'react'
import DropdownTreeSelect from 'react-dropdown-tree-select'
import 'react-dropdown-tree-select/dist/styles.css'
import './test.css'


const data = {
  label: 'search me',
  value: 'searchme',
  children: [
    {
      label: 'search me too',
      value: 'searchmetoo',
      children: [
        {
          label: 'No one can get me',
          value: 'anonymous',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}

export default function testRcTree() {

  const onChange = (currentNode, selectedNodes) => {
    console.log('onChange::', currentNode, selectedNodes)
  }
  const onAction = (node, action) => {
    console.log('onAction::', action, node)
  }
  const onNodeToggle = currentNode => {
    console.log('onNodeToggle::', currentNode)
  }

  return (
    <div >
      <DropdownTreeSelect
        multiSelect
        className='mdl-demo'
        data={data}
        onChange={onChange}
        onAction={onAction}
        onNodeToggle={onNodeToggle} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would need to explicitly mark the checked attribute of parent node as true. There are two variables for a node's parent, "checked" and "expanded" I see expanded is true. But please find the parent of that node,which is sitting at selectedNode.parent and set it as

```
selectedNode.parent.checked=true;
```